# Infinite items loading in Xamarin Forms FlowListView

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, xamarin.forms

I am implementing the **FlowListView** NuGet package for a custom listview with multiple columns.

(NuGet package link: https://www.nuget.org/packages/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls.FlowListView/)

Everything is displayed as it should. But the app is getting very slow. On looking further in the Live Visual Tree I found out that the list items in the FlowListView are loading infinitely. I don't know what is causing it.

Can anyone tell me why it is happening, and how to stop it?

XAML:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:flv="clr-namespace:DLToolkit.Forms.Controls;assembly=DLToolkit.Forms.Controls.FlowListView"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:FlowDemo.ViewModels"
             x:Class="FlowDemo.MainPage">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:MainViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    
    <StackLayout>
        <flv:FlowListView FlowColumnCount="2"
                          RowHeight="50"
                          SeparatorVisibility="Default"
                          HasUnevenRows="false"
                          FlowItemsSource="{Binding Items}" >

            <flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Frame Margin="10" Padding="0" CornerRadius="6" HasShadow="True">

                        <Label Text="{Binding}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />

                    </Frame>
                </DataTemplate>
            </flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>

        </flv:FlowListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

View Model:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace FlowDemo.ViewModels
{
    public class MainViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", };
    }
}
```

Code Behind:

```
using DLToolkit.Forms.Controls;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace FlowDemo
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            FlowListView.Init();
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:
I'm using Visual Studio 2022 and .Net Standard 2.0. I'm also using PropertyChanged.Fody for implementing INotifyPropertyChanged.

Screenshot:
[Click here to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8mC3.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be because MainPage USES FlowListView during InitializeComponent.

**UPDATE** Moving `Init` (as suggested below) did not fix.

---

Need to call `FlowListView.Init()` BEFORE use it.

You COULD do this simply by moving it earlier in MainPage constructor:

```
public MainPage()
{
    FlowListView.Init();
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

But then if you change to a different starting page, you might forget to call it. Therefore, a better place is in

App.xaml.cs:

```
public App()
{
    ...
    FlowListView.Init();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem persists. I've tried placing it both before `InitializeComponent()` and in _App.xaml.cs_, but both of the methods don't seem to work.

Comment: ok. That is surprising. **Are there any errors in VS Output pane, while it runs?** I suggest testing the provided sample in the source - see if it has the same symptom. Download repo https://github.com/daniel-luberda/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls, open tree/master/Samples/DLToolkitControlsSamples/DLToolkitControlsSamples.csproj, build and run. If that has the same problem, post an issue at that github repo's "issues" page.

Comment: If the original sample works, then we need to figure out what is different between it and yours. Next step would be to start over: create a new project, add the minimum code to it to show the problem.